# How to use Aura:Iteration index variable inside a placeholder?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a component which has a list of teams over which the aura:iteration is looping.
I want to use the placeholder attribute of lightning:input as such:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.dToPart.teams}"  var="eachTeam" indexVar="index">
  <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12 " >
    <lightning:input placeholder="{'Name of team '+ #index+1}" aura:id="dToPart" value="{!eachTeam.name}" required="true"/>
  </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

But this gives the following result:

[image: Merge expression of string with aura iteration index fails]

This works perfectly fine, if i only include the index in the merge expression:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.dToPart.teams}"  var="eachTeam" indexVar="index">
  <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12 " >
    <lightning:input placeholder="{'Name of team '+ #index+1}" aura:id="dToPart" value="{!eachTeam.name}" required="true"/>
  </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

[image: Works when merge expression only has index]

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expressions need to start with # or ! to be recognized:

```
<lightning:input placeholder="{#'Name of team '+ (index+1)}" ... />
```

Note that the inner `(` and `)` are necessary to treat the `index + 1` as arithmetic instead of string concatenation.

An expression is always in the form of `{`, followed by `#` or `!`, followed by the expression to be evaluated, and finally ending in `}`.